# XLS to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for software that can help me with that work...

I have an XLS file that store table of about 16k data.
Each column has to become a new table with indexed values and the main table which connects all data by IDs.

For example:

XLS contains

- University Name
- Field of Study

New DB will consist of

- tbl_university (university_id, university_name)
- tbl_field_of_study (fos_id, field_of_study)
- tbl_main (university_id, fos_id)

My platform is Mac OSX, but I can work on Windows 7.

Comment: Export your XLS as a CSV and use the MySQL command line client to import that into the DB.

Comment: @AndréDaniel That would result in a single table with two columns (University name, Field of Study), and thus not correspond to the OPs requirements. Though in a second step, this could be resolved using a stored function in the database, of course ;)